# ggplot2 facet_grid group variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm using the following code to create a facet_grid plot:

```
load(url("http://ebib.com.br/dados.RData"))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot() + geom_step(data=subset(me, variable=="Umid. Relat."), aes(Data, value), color="blue") +
   geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable=="Umid. Relat."), aes(Data, value), , color="blue") +
   geom_line(data=subset(me, variable=="Vel. Vento"), aes(Data, value), color="gray20") +
   geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable=="Vel. Vento"), aes(Data, value), color="gray20") +
   geom_line(data=subset(me, variable==c("Temp. Max.", "Temp. Min.")), aes(Data, value, colour=variable)) +
   geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable==c("Temp. Max.", "Temp. Min.")), aes(Data, value, colour=variable)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", data=subset(me, variable=="Precipitação"), aes(Data, value), fill="blue") +
   facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y") +
   scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
   theme(legend.position="none")
```

Is there a way to plot the variables "Temp. Max." and "Temp. Min." in the same graph/facet?

**Edit: Working code**

```
load(url("http://ebib.com.br/dados.RData"))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

me$variable2 <- as.character(me$variable)
me$variable2[me$variable2 %in% c("Temp. Max.","Temp. Min.")] <- "Temp. Max./Min."

ggplot() + geom_line(data=subset(me, variable=="Umid. Relat."), aes(Data, value), color="blue") +
geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable=="Umid. Relat."), aes(Data, value), , color="blue") +
geom_line(data=subset(me, variable=="Vel. Vento"), aes(Data, value), color="gray20") +
geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable=="Vel. Vento"), aes(Data, value), color="gray20") +
geom_line(data=subset(me, variable==c("Temp. Max.", "Temp. Min.")), aes(Data, value, colour=variable)) +
geom_smooth(data=subset(me, variable==c("Temp. Max.", "Temp. Min.")), aes(Data, value, colour=variable)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", data=subset(me, variable=="Precipitação"), aes(Data, value), fill="blue") +
facet_grid(variable2~., scales="free_y") +
scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Not a very good reproducible example. It would be better if you could give a sample of "me" dataset. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. I'm editing the post right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a new variable for facetting.

The new column `variable2` is almost identical to `variable` but there is a single value `"Temp. Max./Min."` for both `"Temp. Max."` and `"Temp. Min."`.

```
me$variable2 <- as.character(me$variable)
me$variable2[me$variable2 %in% c("Temp. Max.","Temp. Min.")] <- "Temp. Max./Min."
```

Use this variable as an argument for `facet_grid`:

```
facet_grid(variable2 ~., scales = "free_y")
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! I will edit the post with the necessary libraries and the working code.